# ItemsControl Content Sizing issue

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a dock panel of 2 elements, a Map and an editing panel. The Editing panel goes on the bottom, so that the map when docked at the top "Fill"s the rest of the area. I want this bottom editing panel Height to be modififable based on what editing user contrl gets added to it.

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: "I want to be able to have this ItemsControl expand and contract to perfectly fit the contents of the user control that is added to it."?

Comment: That won't happen if you bind the ItemsControl.Height and Width to a value on it's DataContext.

Comment: I wasn't before, I only attempted to do that because I couldn't figure out how to do it another way. So I thought I might try just setting it dynamically, but it doesn't change when I set it dynamically.

Comment: the default template of the `ItemsControl` contains a `StackPanel` that acts as the `ItemsPanel`. It is unclear to me what kind of resizing are you after. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I understand the confusion. Basically I have a dock panel of 2 elements, a Map and an editing panel. The Editing panel goes on the bottom, so that the map when docked at the top "Fill"s the rest of the area. I want this bottom editing panel Height to be modififable based on what editing user contrl gets added to it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to set the **ItemsControl's** Height property to auto, and each time you add or remove a **View** from the **ItemsControl** region, the **Region** would get resized to fit the displayed **Views**.

I've made a small sample so that you could find the configuration easy to understand:

- [ResizedItemsControlRegion](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3EE28791A0DF3126!113&authkey=!AKzsnja5_OFZ6YM&ithint=file,.zip)

Notice that the **EditRegion** docked at the bottom has a border set in order to differentiate both **Regions**.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was trying to figure out.